# Trying to make tab Icons clickable away from TabBar on Android

Tags: android, react-native, tabs

I am trying to make my tab icons to render their screens when clicked upon and when they are not within the TabBar. It is working with IOS but not with Android. It seems that the tab selection range can only be reached within the TabBar and not outside, above that it is not attached to its icons. Is there any way to make it work outside the TabBar when clicking on its icon? Thanks

Another way I tried is by making the TabBar height at a 100% of the screen and making its backgroundColor Transparent to see the screen behind but it shows a white screen instead and hides the content behind it.

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native'
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation'
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'
class DocSelection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      View style = {
        styles.container
      } >

      <
      Text > CustomerService < /Text>

      <
      /View>



    )
  }
}
class Printing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      View style = {
        styles.container
      } >

      <
      Text > hfhdfjedhfeehfjeh < /Text>

      <
      /View>

    )
  }
}
class Design extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      View style = {
        styles.container
      } >

      <
      Text > 874877847484787 < /Text>

      <
      /View>
    )
  }
}
const RouteConfigs = {
    'Home': {
      screen: DocSelection,
      navigationOptions: { //tabBarButtonComponent: tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, horizontal }) => (
        <
        Image style = {
          {
            margin: 15,
            width: 35,
            height: 35,
            tintColor: "red"
          }
        }
        source = {
          require("../Icons/home.png")
        }
        /> ), }, }, 'Order history':{ screen: Printing, navigationOptions: { backgroundColor: '#262A2C', top:-60, borderTopWidth: 0, tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <
        Image style = {
          {
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            tintColor: "red"
          }
        }
        source = {
          require("../Icons/history-clock-button.png")
        }
        /> ), }, }, 'Customer service':{ screen: Design, navigationOptions: { tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <
        Image style = {
          {
            top: 0,
            margin: 15,
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            tintColor: "red"
          }
        }
        source = {
          require("../Icons/customer-service.png")
        }
        /> ), }, }, }; const DrawerNavigatorConfig = { intialRouteName: 'Home', navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: true }, tabBarOptions: { tabStyle:{ top:-130, height:0 }, showLabel: false, style:{ backgroundColor:"rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)" }, }, }; const Navigator = createBottomTabNavigator(RouteConfigs, DrawerNavigatorConfig);
        export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          container: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
            top: 300
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If there was anyone interested in the answer, You just have to create a component and navigate to the concerned tab. Make sure the tab visibility is false and then place the component where you want. This practice will ensure that going back to previous tabs will save your previous state on previous pages.

If anyone is interested I can post an example. There is currently no reply so I will submit this answer instead.

I have structured it a little differently but here is a simpler case i hope would help you
example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,TouchableOpacity, PixelRatio, Image} from 'react-native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'

class Home extends React.Component{

render(){
  const {navigation} = this.props;
  const { routeName } = navigation.state;
return(

 <View style={{flex:1,
 backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("Home")
              }}
                style={ {position: 'relative',
                width:  PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                left: wp('5%'),
                top: hp('11.5%'),
                backgroundColor:routeName==="Home" ? 'black' : 'white' ,
                borderRadius: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40/2 : 45/2}}>
                <Image

                source={require("./Icons/category.png")} 
                //pay FlatIcon or design personal one
                style={{ resizeMode: 'contain',
                width: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                tintColor: routeName==='Home'?'#81F018' : '#262A2C',
                }}
                />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("Alt")
                }}
                  style={ {position: 'relative',
                  width:  PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                  height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  left: wp('5%'),
                  top: hp('11.5%'),
                  backgroundColor:routeName==="Alt" ? 'black' : 'white' ,
                  borderRadius: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40/2 : 45/2}}>
                  <Image

                  source={require("./Icons/category.png")} 
                  //pay FlatIcon or design personal one
                  style={{ resizeMode: 'contain',
                  width: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                  height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                  tintColor: routeName==='Alt'?'#81F018' : '#262A2C',
                  }}
                  />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>)}}



class Alt extends React.Component{

  render(){
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
  return(

   <View style={{flex:1,
   backgroundColor:'white'}}>
   <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("Home")
              }}
                style={ {position: 'relative',
                width:  PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                left: wp('5%'),
                top: hp('11.5%'),
                backgroundColor:routeName==="Home" ? 'black' : 'white' ,
                borderRadius: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40/2 : 45/2}}>
                <Image

                source={require("./Icons/category.png")} 
                //pay FlatIcon or design personal one
                style={{ resizeMode: 'contain',
                width: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                tintColor: routeName==='Home'?'#81F018' : '#262A2C',
                }}
                />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("Alt")
                }}
                  style={ {position: 'relative',
                  width:  PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                  height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40 : 45,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  left: wp('5%'),
                  top: hp('11.5%'),
                  backgroundColor:routeName==="Alt" ? 'black' : 'white' ,
                  borderRadius: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 40/2 : 45/2}}>
                  <Image

                  source={require("./Icons/category.png")} 
                  //pay FlatIcon or design personal one
                  style={{ resizeMode: 'contain',
                  width: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                  height: PixelRatio.get() <= 2 ? 25 : 30,
                  tintColor: routeName==='Alt'?'#81F018' : '#262A2C',
                  }}
                  />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>)}}
const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({



  "Home": {
    screen: Home,

 },


  "Alt": {
    screen: Alt,

 },


   }, 
   {
       defaultNavigationOptions: {

           tabBarVisible: false
         },


   }
   )
export default createAppContainer(AppTabNavigator)
```